# Multiple select form element from MySQL recordset in PHP update form

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called empicons that has two columns: EmpNo, IconId

I have the EmpNo stored as a session called $EmpNo

I have another table called icons that has 3 columns: Id, Name, URL

Currently I have a recordset that selects the icons table Id and Name and presents it in a Multiple Select box that then updates the empicons table.

Recordset query: SELECT id, name FROM gbl_icons ORDER BY id ASC

Multiple Select Form Element:

```
<select name="icons[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_icons['id']?>"><?php echo $row_icons['name']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_icons = mysql_fetch_assoc($icons));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($icons);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($icons, 0);
      $row_icons = mysql_fetch_assoc($icons);
  }
?>
          </select>
```

I'm trying to do a join with empicons and icons table so that the Multiple Select highlights the data elements found in empicons based on the EmpNo variable.  I cannot get the join to work correctly and then update the form element to highlight these.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, the mysql_* is existing code, is there a way you can formulate and answer using PDO or MySQLi I can use to learn from, @PolishPrince?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i
LEFT JOIN empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = '$EmpNo'
ORDER BY i.id ASC
```

So you will get all icons from your 'gbl_icons' table and for each one of them a corresponding record in empicons for the current EmpNo. If there is no corresponding record you will get NULL in the 'EmpNo' column.

And your code should be like that

```
<select name="icons[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<?php
while($row_icons = mysqli_fetch_assoc($icons)) {  
?>
<option value="<?=$row_icons['id']?>" <?=!empty($row_icons['EmpNo']) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?><?=$row_icons['name']?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It uses `mysqli_` functions. If you're having a problem with `JOIN`ing the two tables, then we need to work on your query.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM gbl_icons ORDER BY id ASC";

echo '<select name="icons[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">';

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row[id] . '">' . $row[name] . '</option>';
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

echo '</select>';

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```